# Custom code for converting html to image which can be passed on to blob and rendered as an image in other screens

Tags: html, css, angular, image, blob

My objective is to convert the html code to image(svg or canvas) [the recommended way as it has to be again rendered in other screens] and pass it on as a blob to backend (I am using Angular7)

```
uploadfloor(): void {
  let file1 = document.getElementsById('toget')[0].outerHTML;
  let svgBlob = new Blob([file1], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });
  let file = this.fileUploadService.convertToFile(svgBlob, "abc.svg");
  this.fileUploadService.uploadFile(file)
 }

  <div class="anystyle" id="toget" appDropzone    appMovableArea 
  (drop)="move(currentBox, dropzone1)"  [ngStyle]=" 
   {'width':'100%','background-image': 'url('+url+')', 'background-repeat': 
   'no-repeat', 'background-position': 'center', 'background-size': '100% 
     100%'}">
           <div *ngFor="let box of dropzone1" class="box"
             appDroppable (dragStart)="currentBox = box" appMovable>
                {{ box.dis }}
           </div>
  </div>
```

I had gone through references,stackoverflow but everywhere external libraries have been used.
Please help.Thanks

After following through the answer I am able to upload and render the image but the issue now is the position of child divs(using *ngFor="let box of dropzone1") placed within parent div(parent div id="toget") before creating the blob and and after retrieving it from the blob is not same which beats the whole purpose. Please suggest how the conversion should be done of html to blob and then retrieving data from blob and converting it back to html.

The code I have tried are as below

For creating blob from html

```
var newString = new 
  XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('toget'));

  var newBlob = new Blob([newString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" 
 });

  let file = this.convertToFile(newBlob, "floorPlan.svg");
  this.uploadFile(file);


  convertToFile(blobFile: Blob, fileName: string): File {
  let blob: any = blobFile;

  blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  blob.name = fileName;
  return <File>blobFile;
}

  this.uploadFile(file, this.siteRef, this.floorRef).subscribe()

  uploadFile(file){
  return this.uploadToBlobStorage(file)
      .pipe(map(progress => this.mapProgress(file, progress)));
      }
```

The blob data which I receive for reference:

```
"<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c18="" appdropzone="" 
appmovablearea=""
class="dropzone fs-settings__upload-section__floor-wrapper__preview- 
image__image-area" id="toget" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"
style="width: 100%; background-image: 
url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALoAAAC6CAMAAAAu0KfDAAAAwFBMVEX////  
k9ykpOc5CQnOcnR8n/9ySZhLa0CgAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: 
no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 100% 100%;"> 
<!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}--><div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable="" class="box 
draggable movable ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none" style="transform: 
translateX(798.4px) translateY(15.2px);">
vav21 </div><div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable="" class="box 
 draggable movable ng-star-inserted" 
touch-action="none" style="transform: translateX(22.4px) 
translateY(58.4px);"> vav22 </div></div>"
```

And the code for rendering the blob to html.The

```
this.getBlobToText('abc', (err, data) => {
    xy.image = (data) ? data  : 'not loaded';
}

<div [innerHTML]="xy.image"></div>
```

Hoping atleast now I would be getting a solution.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
};
img.src = url;
```

*I am using "svg". You can also use any html tag*

Comment: thanks for the quick response but that is my issue as I am appending divs to the outer div containing image, is there a possibility to convert the div elements to image, and whole div whatever I have mentioned in my question needs to be converted to image which will be passed as blob

Comment: I was trying this , could you please explain var url, img.onload, img.src , what they are for and also getElementbyId "canvas", I didn't understand, I am not having any element with id canvas

Comment: var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg); createObjectURL creates your svg to base64 url.

Comment: Please explain why we have  takenvar canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

Comment: if you want to html to image you must have to use canvas tag.

Comment: ok but I have to convert it to image and pass it as a blob, then from where are we using  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); as I dont have any element with id "canvas", are you able to understand my need

Comment: 1) Convert the div element to image 2)Pass that image to blob .These are the first 2 steps I want to do

Comment: Please explain in the answer itself so that it would be easier for me to understand

Comment: I had used only 2 lines of your code and it seems to be working but not as expected ,var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));                             var svg = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });, so what other lines are performing

Comment: are the rest line of code(except the 2 lines mentioned in above comment)  to get the blob(image) and then draw in a canvas, please explain

Comment: as I told the html I am able to pass it as a blob and also able to render it , but the issue is the child divs (*ngFor="let box of dropzone1") which I am placing at a particular positions before passing it as a blob does not remain intact when I render the blob in another screen , could you please help me out

Comment: please if you could explain, as I told the html code I was able to send as blob and render it in the html , however the child div elements of "let box of dropzone1" are not in the same position placed before sending it as a blob